# Unable to order child objects in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query that works when executed against data in memory but doesn't work correctly when using EF.

First, here is my query (Note that I have changed the query to only operate on a single value, **`justOneDcn`**, instead of the whole `context.RepairDocuments` so that the generated SQL is much cleaner to read):

```cs
var justOneDcn = context.RepairDocuments.Where(d => d.Dcn = "00001");
var q = from dcn in justOneDcn
    let orderedHistory = dcn.History.OrderBy(h => h.Date)
    let xdaHistoryPoint = orderedHistory.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Status == DocumentStatus.Xda)
    select xdaHistoryPoint;
```

I have removed unnecessary extra code. The problem is that EF is generating this SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    [... col list ...]
    CASE WHEN ([Element1].[id] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Element1].[date] ELSE @p__linq__0 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
        FROM [dbo].[repair_document] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE N'00001' = [Extent1].[dcn] ) AS [Filter1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [... col list ...]
        FROM [dbo].[repair_document_history] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Filter1].[id] = [Extent2].[repair_document_id]) AND (4 =  CAST( [Extent2].[status] AS int)) AND ( CAST( [Extent2].[status] AS int) IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Element1]
-- p__linq__0: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
```

But the above SQL gives back wrong data, it should add `ORDER BY [Extent2].date` after the where clause. The following modified SQL gives me correct result:

```sql
 SELECT 
    [... col list ...]
    CASE WHEN ([Element1].[id] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Element1].[date] ELSE @p__linq__0 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
        FROM [dbo].[repair_document] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE N'00001' = [Extent1].[dcn] ) AS [Filter1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [... col list ...]
        FROM [dbo].[repair_document_history] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Filter1].[id] = [Extent2].[repair_document_id]) AND (4 =  CAST( [Extent2].[status] AS int)) AND ( CAST( [Extent2].[status] AS int) IS NOT NULL) 
        ORDER BY [Extent2].date) AS [Element1]
-- p__linq__0: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
```

Notice the `ORDER BY` at the end.

This is driving me crazy! What am I doing wrong? Also, loading data to memory is not an option, I have about 5000 Dcns with each dcn having 10-15 records in it's history table.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the Entity declaration

```
public class RepairDocument {
   /* .... */
   public virtual ICollection<RepairDocumentHistory> History { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you instead used:

```
var justOneDcn = context.RepairDocuments.Where(d => d.Dcn = "00001").OrderBy(d => d.History.Date);
```

And *removed* the `OrderBy` from the command below that.

Comment: That won't compile. `History` is a child collection of `RepairDocuments`

Comment: then include it like contex.RepairDocumets.Inclue("History") and try the order by

Comment: Sorry user1718673, you are completely right. What if you select the child table History as your main entity and then Include the Parent? Then you can easily order by the main entity you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
var item =
(from r in context.RepairDocuments
from h in r.History
where r.Dcn == "00001" && h.Status == DocumentStatus.Xda
orderby h.Date
select h).FirstOrDefault();
```